# How to randomly choose one of the lines with gghighlight and highlight it?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data.table

Using the example in [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gghighlight/vignettes/gghighlight.html), if I have a bunch of line, how can I randomly choose one of them if the data points connected to each other to form a line according to, say `ID`, column in the data table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sample()` function to grab a value at random.  If your dataframe is called `df`, I'd think something like this for your `gghighlight()` line:

```
# your plot code = p
p + gghighlight(ID == sample(unique(df$ID),1))
```

That would highlight one value from the vector of unique values in `df$ID` at random.  It's important to note that if you want this to *always* be random and you have elsewhere in a script beforehand set any random seed, you will need to *reset* the random seed.  Either of these options would be a good way to do that:

```
set.seed(NULL)
set.seed(Sys.time())
```

In the example from `gghighlight` you linked, this is how you would add to that script to ensure that you picked a line at random (since the data is generated consistently by `set.seed(2)` in the beginning of the code):

```
set.seed(NULL)

ggplot(d) +
  geom_line(aes(idx, value, colour = type)) +
  gghighlight(sample(type==unique(d$type),1))
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I would also appreciate an answer to this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66754302/accessing-the-values-of-the-reduced-dataset-after-facet-grid-in-ggplot) if you have one