# Accessing the values of the reduced dataset after facet_grid in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, gghighlight

Building on [this earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66752860/6708910) question, let's say the data table has columns `ID,factor,SimulationID,Data`. During the plotting, we want to plot a new graph. for each `(factor, SimulationID)` tuple using `facet_grid()`. And for each of these plots, we will use `ID` varialbe to connect to `Data` points as a line. However, the set of unique `ID` values in for each `(factor, SimulationID)` tuple are different from each other.

Now, What I want is to highlight one of the curves in each of these plots separated by `facet_grid()`.

```
ggplot(d) +
facet_grid(factor~SimulationID,)+
  geom_line(aes(idx, value, colour = type)) +
  gghighlight(ID == <choose a valid ID randomly>)
```

Comment: Hi, OP.  Please, provide a dataset that can be used to create a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Also, it's not exactly clear from your question what you are trying to accomplish and where your having difficulty.

Comment: @chemdork123 I hope it is more clear now